# Distance beetween hours in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I have a problem with my application. In there I want to search distance hour between my column mulai & durasi the result in the column total, column total is result from distance data column mulai until data column durasi. Any idea?

```
$simpan= array();
    $simpan['nama']=Request::input('nama');
    $simpan['tanggal']=Request::input('tanggal');
    $simpan['deskripsi']=Request::input('deskripsi');
    $simpan['mulai']=Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', Request::input('mulai'))->toTimeString();
    $simpan['durasi']=Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', Request::input('durasi'))->toTimeString();
    $simpan['total'] = ???
```

Answer (score 1):

use diffInHours() method since you are using carbon.

```
$mulai  = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', Request::input('mulai'));
$durasi = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', Request::input('durasi'));
$total  = $durasi->diffInHours($mulai);
```

check it here
http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `durasi` time to `mulai`. Code:

```
$mulai  = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', Request::input('mulai'));
$durasi = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', Request::input('durasi'));
$total  = $mulai->addHours($durasi->format('H'))->addMinutes($durasi->format('i'));
dd($total->format('%h:%I'));
```

Comment: yes i know, but is doesnt answer my problem for example : when i input data in my column durasi : 00:40 and i input in column mulai 17:00 i get result : 16:20, but the result should be 07:40. 
have u do that ?

Comment: and its should save to database and show in my view.

Comment: @ivansetiadi I improved my answer, check it now.

Comment: its only show wrong answer. have you try again. please for me.

Comment: @ivansetiadi Whoops, found a TYPO. Now it works as it should http://s32.postimg.org/ft5nmddt1/Screenshot_from_2016_05_11_08_26_34.png